# How to replace selected UILabels with UITextFields in IB?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have a view with big amount of UILabels, and now they need to be editable, so i have to replace them with UITextFields. Is there any quick way to do it? Or i have to replace them one-by-one? Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace them all, there is no quicker way.